# What is correct syntax to apply security globally for OpanApi 3.0 and PHP attributes with swagger-php

Tags: swagger-php

I am using PHP attributes to produce my OpenApi yaml file specfication/documentation and then using Swagger UI to interact with it.
I have the following defined which creates the .yaml file without any problem

```
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;

#[OA\OpenApi(
    info: new OA\Info(
       ...
    ),
    servers: [
        new OA\Server(
            ...
        ),
    ],
    components: new OA\Components(
        parameters: [
            new OA\Parameter(
                ...
            ),
        ],
        responses: [
            new OA\Response( 
                ...
            ),   
        ],
        securitySchemes: [
            new OA\SecurityScheme(
                securityScheme: 'BearerAuth',
                description: 'this is the beaer security scheme',
                type: 'http',
                scheme: 'bearer',
                name: 'Authorization',
                in: 'header'
            )
        ],
    ),
    tags: [
        new OA\Tag(
            ...
        )
    ]
)]
```

I want to apply the bearer security globally so know I need to add something along the lines of

`security: [ 'BearerAuth': [] ]`

below or above tags: however this is generating an error
.. Error: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token ":", expecting "]" in  ...

If I leave out this security definition from the class file and then manually add the following to the .yaml file
`security: - Bearer: []`
then it all works as expected.

So my question what is the correct syntax for the `security:`  declaration

I have tried a number of different ways but all have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I think this is the correct way (according to https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/cookbook.html#default-security-scheme-for-all-endpoints)

Just remember that with `Attributes` you are writing proper PHP code, not PHPDoc, so it should probably be

```
security: [ 'BearerAuth' => [] ]
```

Comment: security: [ 'BearerAuth' => [] ] 
didn't work for me but wrapping it in another [] did so the working code for me was security: [ ['BearerAuth' => []] ]
thanks